# How can I easily revert changes on a DataBound form?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

If I have a form with controls DataBound to an instance variable object, is there a way to  do revert changes that the user made, possibly by doing something like:

```
myLocalObject = DataLayer.GetCurrentState();
```

and have the form's controls (bound to myLocalObject) automatically pick up the changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the following does the trick:

```
var myLocalObject = DataLayer.GetCurrentState();
LayoutRoot.DataContext = null;
LayoutRoot.DataContext = myLocalObject;
```

For some reason, if I don't set DataContext to null, my bound controls don't pick up the changes when changes are reverted.

Comment: That "some reason" you mention is due to the state object overriding `Equals`. See my post here for an explanation: http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/03/beware-datacontext-and-equals.html. Also, your workaround is very reliant on the specifics of your data layer - it is not a general solution.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into the [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) interface.